# Can you set a partial schema for an object in mongoosejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Can you set a partial schema for an object in mongoosejs?  Say I have a person object and I want to validate that it always has a first_name and last_name field.  But I also want to allow users to save other fields of their choosing. Say I have the following schema:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  first_name  : { type: String, required: "first name required" }
  last_name   : { type: String, required: "last name required" }
})
```

But I want the app to be able to post this:

```
{
  first_name: "john",
  last_name: "doe",
  field_not_in_schema: "info"
}
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `Schema.Types.Mixed` field, which is a freeform JS object:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  first_name  : { type: String, required: "first name required" },
  last_name   : { type: String, required: "last name required" },
  data        : { type: Schema.Types.Mixed }
})
```

Here is how you would populate it:

```
var user = new User({
  first_name: 'John',
  last_name: 'Doe',
  data: { sex: 'Male', eyeColor: 'blue' }
});
user.save(...);
```

Comment: Well, that's not exactly what I wanted but it might work.  I was hoping to be able to add extra fields, not have the data all under one extra preset field.